# Why does the bicycle move forward after I give it an impulse with the help of brakes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, inertia

Whenever I need to slow down my bicycle I use brakes, momentarily pressing them and then releasing. For some reason, this momentarily halts the bicycle and when I release the brakes, the bicycle continues to move forward albeit with a velocity less than what it was before.

So far I haven't broken any bones while riding the bicycle, so I guess I can use this method, but what I am confused about is that if the bicycle momentarily comes to almost standstill, why does it move again? Shouldn't it stay at rest once it stops? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: How about making a video of yourself on the bicycle braking to a stop and then rolling again?

Answer (score 3):

When you tap the breaks, the bicycle stops but your body keeps moving. Almost immediately after you let go of the breaks you push/hit the front handlebars and the bike keeps going. Having your bike coming to a full stop (without your body slowing down) without problems is only possible at low speeds. At higher speeds the bike probably doesn't slow down as much as it feels like it does.